# Hacer click en pagina emergente

Tags: javascript, script, onclick, click, timeout

Intento hacer un script que realice las siguientes acciones:

> 1. Que tenga un temporizador de 2 segundos y realice un click en un enlace y abra una pagina emergente.
> 2. Que realice un click al segundo 5 dentro de la pagina que hizo inicialmente el 1º click.
> 3. Que cierre a los 10 segundo las pagina emergente.

Puesto que yo no soy muy bueno escribiendo Javascript he llegado a conseguir que solo funcione las 1º y 3º accion con este codigo:

```
<a id="dynLink"> ventana emergente</a>

<script>    
    
window.setTimeout("autoClick()", 2000);
function autoClick() {
  var linkPage = document.getElementById('dynLink').href;
  var myWindow = window.open("https://www.google.com", "myWindow", "width=1000, height=525");
  setTimeout(function(){ myWindow.close() }, 10000);
}


</script>
```

Alguien podria ayudarme a crear este script ?

Answer (score 1):

Hacer lo que buscas solo funcionara en tu mismo dominio. No es posible hacerlo (por lo menos de manera fácil) sin desactivar la [política de mismo orígen del navegador](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25098021/4326551)

Para correr este snipet necesitas correrlo desde un servidor.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let link = document.getElementById("dynLink")
  link.onclick = click
}

function click() {

  let contador = 0
  let newWindow = null
  let intervalo = setInterval(_ => {
    console.log("Tiempo: ", contador)
    if (contador === 2) {
      newWindow = primeraAccion() 
      }
    if (contador === 5) {
       segundaAccion(newWindow)
    }
    if (contador === 10) {
      terceraAccion()
      clearInterval(intervalo)
    }
    contador++

  }, 1000)

}


function primeraAccion() {
  var linkPage = document.getElementById('dynLink').href;
  var myWindow = window.open("https://www.google.com", "myWindow", "width=1000, height=525");
  return myWindow
}

function segundaAccion(window) {
  let links = window.getElementByTagName("a")

  console.log(links)
}


function terceraAccion() {

  console.log("Tercera accion")


}
```

```html
<a id="dynLink" href="javascript:void(0)">Click</a>
```

Esto te dara el error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1:5500" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
> at segundaAccion (http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html:47:28)
> at http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html:26:13

Editando ...